# How Can I add rows to a query depending on data in specific fields

Tags: sql, oracle

Easiest way I can explain this is with a example

This is what my Query is currently returning

```
studNr    mark    module    result
123       47      DNP       (null)
123       39      EKS01     fail
123       64      MOD01     passed
123       70      PRAK      (null)
123       59      KLS01     (null)
```

What I need is to put the result value `where module = "MOD01"` on a new row in the mark column and put `result` as that rows module value

I need the Query to return Example:

```
studNr    mark    module    
123       47      DNP       
123       39      EKS01     
123       64      MOD01     
123       70      PRAK      
123       59      KLS01     
123       passed  result
```

Comment: You should better do that in your logic and not in SQL.

Comment: Is your `mark` column an integer or string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's a integer

Comment: @LegionDev . . . Why do you want to put a string value in what would otherwise be an integer column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to give that query to iReport, which will pivot the data using crosstab on module, creating a column for each module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a union.

Something like this.

*Note, this turns mark into a string.  The field will sort alphabetically rather than numerically.

```
SELECT StudNr,
       mark || '' mark,
       module
from table1
union
SELECT studNr,
       result mark,
       'result' module
from table1
where module = 'MOD01'
```

Comment: If you fix the `result` value, then the answer will be correct.

Comment: I end up getting this error 
[`ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`]

Comment: @LegionDev  That makes sense, your mark value is an integer but 'passed' is clearly not.  You may be able force mark to string by concatenating a blank string.  mark || '' mark

Comment: Ah got it working, used CAST( mark AS varchar2(30)) , Thanks a million @TomHubbard

Comment: @LegionDev  Great.  Keep in mind, sorting will be alphabetical rather than numerical from then on.